# Apache RewriteRule with a RewriteMap variable substitution for the VAL argument to environment variable

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, rewritemap

I have an Apache server that serves up binary files to an application (not a browser).

The application making the request wants the HTTP Content-MD5 header in HEX format.  The default and only option within Apache is Base64. If I  add "ContentDigest on" to my VirtualHost, I get this header in Base64.

So I wrote a perl script, md5digesthex.pl, that gives me exactly what I want:  MD5 in HEX format but I'm struggling with the RewriteRule to get my server to send the result.

Here is my current Rewrite recipe:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap md5inhex prg:/www/download/md5digesthex.pl
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/download/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI} [E=HASH:${md5inhex:$1}]
Header set Content-MD5 "%{HASH}e" env=HASH
```

The problem is that I can't seem to set the HASH environment variable based on the output of the md5inhex map function.  It appears this behavior is not supported and I'm at a lost as to how to formulate this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better question is, why are you redefining what the [RFC already defines](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1864.txt)?  If you're trying to overload the Content-MD5 header, chances are you should just be using a different header.  If you're trying to adapt this to your program, it sounds to me like your program is doing the wrong thing and should be corrected.

EDIT: So I looked at this locally.  Can you tell me what the output of md5digesthex.pl is?  It *should* be a whitespace delimited pair of values, i.e.:

```
some/path/to/file somehash
```

It sounds like the key/value may not be matching up, because this WILL do what you want assuming `${md5inhex:$1}` executes correctly.  What you can try doing, for testing, is setting a dummy variable; i.e:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap md5inhex prg:/www/download/md5digesthex.pl
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/download/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI} [E=HASH:${md5inhex:$1}]
Header set Content-MD5 "%{HASH}e" env=HASH

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=TEST_HASH:${md5inhex:somekey}]
Header set TestingHeader "%{TEST_HASH}e" env=TEST_HASH
```

You can use something like `curl -I <server>/<path>` to verify that its getting set.  I can verify that using a correctly formatted RewriteMap, this WILL set your info correctly.

Comment: very true.  I guess I need to explain why I need to solve this?  OK, it's a very large system.  Some 4 or 5 back end systems that all use the same MD5 in hex format and the client is at some 30,000 locations.  When you have a very large system such as this, you simply can not change the client and be done.  This is a tactical approach until a more strategic architecture can be developed.  We currently serve up binaries from a database application and the load is growing too high hence the reason to move to a web server.

Comment: Ah, I gotcha.  Don't you just wish you could have a talk to the people who developed that? -.-  Anyways, I updated my answer to help you debug the issue; hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, wish I was around to slap the original developers.  Anyway, the output of the md5inhex is just a hex string.  I pass it the name of a file, it computes the MD5 and returns the hex value i.e. 0xBADBEEF.... I've tested it on the command line and it works and a browser test prompts me to download the file but HTTP header never gets set.

Comment: When you use the `prg:/path/to/filename`, it expects a key/value pair separated with whitespace.  What it does right now is, it looks for a key calculated from `$1`, which would be the path that was matched.  What you'll want to do is have the program output a pair (a constant key, and a calculated value), and use that key in `${md5inhex:somekey}`.

Comment: I solved it.  I overlooked the fact that the md5digesthex.pl had to be a long running app.  So I change the perl code run inside a while(<STDIN>) loop instead and I now get the desired results... Thanks for the help.